# How to create views dynamically from json in android listview?

Tags: android, json, android-view

I want to create radio button,checkbox,spinner dynamically from web service. Below is my response.

```
{
    "getSurvey": {
        "ErrorCode": "0",
        "Result": "Success",
        "Response": [
            {
                "SurveyId": "91",
                "SurveyName": "Sample Survey",
                "Questions": [
                    {
                        "QuestionId": "553",
                        "QuestionText": "<p style=\"margin: 0px; text-align: left;\">Are you satisfied with Cement Quality?</p>",
                        "Type": "RadioButtonList",
                        "Mandatory": "Y",
                        "OptionValue": [
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2220",
                                "AnswerValue": "Excellent"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2221",
                                "AnswerValue": "Good"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2222",
                                "AnswerValue": "Satisfactory"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2223",
                                "AnswerValue": "Poor"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "QuestionId": "554",
                        "QuestionText": "How will you rate Cement? (0= Lowest and 7= Highest)&nbsp;",
                        "Type": "DropDownList",
                        "Mandatory": "Y",
                        "OptionValue": [
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2224",
                                "AnswerValue": "0"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2225",
                                "AnswerValue": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2226",
                                "AnswerValue": "2"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2227",
                                "AnswerValue": "3"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2228",
                                "AnswerValue": "4"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2229",
                                "AnswerValue": "5"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2230",
                                "AnswerValue": "6"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2231",
                                "AnswerValue": "7"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "QuestionId": "555",
                        "QuestionText": "What Kind of issues you face while Delivery?",
                        "Type": "ListBox",
                        "Mandatory": "Y",
                        "OptionValue": [
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2232",
                                "AnswerValue": "Logistic Issue"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2233",
                                "AnswerValue": "Material Handeling "
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2234",
                                "AnswerValue": "Stock not available"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2235",
                                "AnswerValue": "Wastage of Cement"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2236",
                                "AnswerValue": "Others"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "QuestionId": "559",
                        "QuestionText": "Do you like Cement?",
                        "Type": "CheckBoxList",
                        "Mandatory": "Y",
                        "OptionValue": [
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2237",
                                "AnswerValue": "Yes"
                            },
                            {
                                "AnswerId": "2238",
                                "AnswerValue": "No"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Based on type i need to create views dynamically. Please someone give me the idea or solution how to achieve this. After created views dynamically i need to get all the selected values from created views.

Thanks.

Comment: are you displaying response in listview or where?

Comment: @bharat I don't know how to create and show view for that response..But I need to show in linear layout..

Comment: @ShanmugaM found this https://github.com/vijayrawatsan/android-json-form-wizard now. see if it helps. not sure if it suits your requirement.

Comment: Nice solution at https://mobikul.com/how-to-get-data-from-dynamically-created-views-android/

Comment: even to come up with this idea, is great thinking. upvoted you.

Answer (score 7):

you can use json2view library to create dynamically view.

https://github.com/Avocarrot/json2view

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky, you need to learn how to create layouts dynamically in code first. I would start off my reviewing tutorials found here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

You would need to create a class that could parse this data and create the views specifically for your values. Once that is done, you could read the data again or have it stored so you could load the data to the screen. This could also be done at the same time you are creating the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..Can you please tell me how to place corresponding QuestionText below that corresponding OptionValue for dynamic view in linear layout.

Comment: This helped me when I started using `JSON` in my project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

There are several websites that walk you through parsing `JSON` objects. This really depends on what the structure of the `JSON` is and how it is laid out. I would go here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and put you `JSON` in and see what is an `Array` and what is an `Object`, the go from there.

Comment: I successfully parsed that response and  stored in array list. But i don't how to create view for all the questions with corresponding option.

Comment: The Dreamincode.net link above should get you goin. Basically, you will need to create a class to handle and process the data. You can create functions that take in the data to use. Based on the data you receive in, you can create you different buttons, check boxes, and so on. Then you will add what you have just created to your view. I would recommend looking over that website and go from there. You will use `.addView()` in Android to add to the few and `this.setContentView()` to set the view once everything is added or updated.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of Questions like `'"Type": "RadioButtonList"'` are known in advance, you can create predefined layouts addressing each of those types. You then need to parse and look for the object /Response/Questions/Type in your json and inflate the appropriate layout. You also need to create an adapter that can accept list of options for each type. Plugin the adapter and the view behind the layout.

I do something similar for the product I work on. After I retrieve the json feed, I would scan through the Questions to see the type of layouts I require. In my scenario, I create a ViewPager dynamically: each entry into the view pager would have a layout corresponding to the Type of Question. I would then build up the list of options for each Question Type and feed them to an adapter that is bound to listview or drop down list or a custom type that resides in the layout file.

Comment: Hi can you give  me the piece of code to display questions and options ?

Answer (score 0):

just parse and set data to static data in code

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);


    //radio list
    RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this); 
    group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

    RadioButton btn1 = new RadioButton(this);
    btn1.setText("BTN1");
    group.addView(btn1);

    RadioButton btn2 = new RadioButton(this);
    btn2.setText("BTN2");
    group.addView(btn2);

    ll.addView(group);


    //drop down
    Spinner spiner = new Spinner(this);
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("Spinner - one");
    data.add("Spinner - two");
    data.add("Spinner - three");
    data.add("Spinner - four");
    data.add("Spinner - five");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
    spiner.setAdapter(adapter);

    ll.addView(spiner);

    //listview
    ListView listData = new ListView(this);
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    dataList.add("List - one");
    dataList.add("List - two");
    dataList.add("List - three");
    dataList.add("List - four");
    dataList.add("List - five");
    dataList.add("List - six");
    dataList.add("List - seven");
    dataList.add("List - eight");
    dataList.add("List - nine");
    dataList.add("List - ten");
    dataList.add("List - eleven");
    dataList.add("List - twelve");
    dataList.add("List - thirteen");
    dataList.add("List - fourteen");
    dataList.add("List - fifteen");
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);
    listData.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    ll.addView(listData);
    this.setContentView(sv);

    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listData);
```

support method

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Hi Each question has different options. How to create view  for options dynamically based on options length.

Comment: options is JSON Array, so as per getting json array length, you can create radio buttons.

Comment: Hi I don't know the way to create. Can you please create sample for that response ?

Comment: sorry dear, i can give you food recipes but i can not making a food for you, that much you have to do your self.

Comment: HI please create for one options

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it might help you.

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String response = "";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  try {
   JSONObject jObject1 = new JSONObject(response);
   JSONObject jObject2 = jObject1.getJSONObject("getSurvey");
   if (jObject2.getString("ErrorCode").equals("0")) {
    JSONArray jArray = jObject2.getJSONArray("Response");
    JSONObject jObject3 = jArray.getJSONObject(0);// Response array
                // contains only
                // one object ,
                // otherwise we
                // can put loop
    JSONArray jArray2 = jObject3.getJSONArray("Questions");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray2.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject jObjectQ = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);
     String QUESTION = jObjectQ.getString("QuestionText"); // Similarly
                   // you
                   // can
                   // take
                   // other
                   // parameters.
     JSONArray jArrayA = jObjectQ.getJSONArray("OptionValue");
     for (int j = 0; j < jArrayA.length(); j++) {
      JSONObject jObjectOPTION = jArrayA.getJSONObject(j);
      String ANSWERID = jObjectOPTION.getString("AnswerId");
      String ANSWERVALUE = jObjectOPTION
        .getString("AnswerValue");

      // Add Dynamically in Spinner or create Radiobutton as
      // per your requirement
     }

    }

   }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
}
```

You can also set Id dynamically of each controls. based on that you should call any method and check id of the controls.

Comment: Hi Arth Tilva I need that code only to create view